# Clicking a tag in div dropdown in Selenium Python, nothing is working

Tags: python, selenium, click

I am trying to click an a tag inside a div dropdown. I have tried 4 code options and nothing works. I know the XPATH is right. I have implicit sleep on.

1.)              `browser.find_element_by_xpath(OrderOrderTypeXPATH).send_keys('/n')`

2.)

```
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click()',
browser.find_element_by_xpath(OrderTypeXPATH))
```

3.)

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_xpath(OrderTypeXPATH)).click().perform()
```

4.)

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(OrderTypeXPATH).click()
```

My div code looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown"> <!-- hidden before, clicked hamburger menu -->

    <a href="#" class="active menu-option">Order 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-option">Order 2</a> <!-- want to click this! -->
    <a href="#" class="menu-option">Order 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-option">Order 4</a>

</div>
```

There is no error messages. Just doesn't click it and the dropdown just disappears.

XPATH is right because sendKeys('\n') outputs an outline.

Comment: what is the xpath you are using

Comment: It is from the whole page! limitOrderTypeXPATH = "//h3[text() = 'Order Type']/../../div/a[2]. I am certain it works because it outlines.

Comment: I think your xpath is in fact wrong. You say it outputs the outline... it shouldn't be able to do that on an A element. I think you're clicking on the input box for the search. Please add the xpath & the html.

Comment: Possibly. This is it: This is the code... https://prnt.sc/p1blu6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`  and `element_to_be_clickable()` and click the div element first and then click the desire element like below.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.dropdown"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='dropdown']/a[text()='Order 2']"))).click()
```

**Note**: You need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

**Edited**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://robinhood.com/stocks/AMD")
driver.maximize_window()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//h3[contains(.,'Buy AMD')]/following::*[name()='svg'][2]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//h3[contains(.,'Order Type')]/following::div/a[text()='Limit Order']"))).click()
```

Comment: I got a long traceback error: ending with File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Comment: @JoeD : Did you copy exact code what I have posted?

Comment: I had to change driver to webdriver since I had it as from selenium import webdriver, then the xpath had to include the root of the page but that is it.

Comment: This works on hamburger icon: # click hamburger menu icon
hamburger = browser.find_element_by_xpath(hamburgerOrderFormXPATH)
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', hamburger)

Comment: Then the code I had pasted now giving error: WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, hamburgerOrderFormXPATH))).click()
                    WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, limitOrderTypeXPATH))).click()

Comment: Tried commenting out hamburger part but other part still gives error and doesn't click.

Comment: Can you share your url if possible?

Comment: Do you have robinhood? It's the order page where you can buy shares of a stock. here's an example: https://robinhood.com/stocks/AMD

Comment: Then here is an image of what it would look like: https://prnt.sc/p1bjoq , need to click limit order.

Comment: How is this related to your post?Anyways I’ll look into it sometimes later.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am trying to click limit order. I have been trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: @JoeD : Try the edited code.It should work.I have tested.

Comment: Copied it exactly and just added my webdriver path. Stalls out and doesn't see hamburger menu... This has to be my machine chrome version issue? I am on a Mac Chrome 76.0.3809.132. What are you on?

Comment: OH. Your code works. But the moment I add chrome options/cache/cookies for my login it messes up. What the heck.

Comment: No Idea.Mine is windows 10 and working perfectly.I can’t go beyond that.Just check what you messed up.I can’t help you there.

Comment: Ok it was my options... I deleted the cache folder for chrome for my selenium instances and now your solution works.. Weird.. and the sendkeys one worked until Friday. Not sure how that can happen.